# Get checkbox state and click accordingly using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

When i use below pywinauto code, i am getting error saying

```
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import ButtonWrapper 
checkbox = ButtonWrapper(app.Dialog.child_window(title='Has Balance',auto_id='HasBalanceCheckEdit',control_type='CheckBox').TCheckBox.WrapperObject())
print(checkbox.GetCheckState())
```

Error:

```
raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'TCheckBox' in 'dict_keys(['Has Balance', 'Has BalanceStatic', 'Static'])'
```

Comment: This message clearly says there is no such child with name `TCheckBox`. Maybe you don't need additional attribute expansion? Can you also provide a screenshot from Spy++ with part of the GUI hierarchy?

Comment: here is the output from "print_control_identifiers(depth=2)"Custom - ''    (L-1778, T674, R-1617, B740)
['', 'Custom']
child_window(auto_id="AdditionalFilters", control_type="Custom")
   |
   | CheckBox - 'Has Balance'    (L-1773, T674, R-1622, B696)
   | ['CheckBox', 'Has BalanceCheckBox', 'Has Balance', 'Has Balance0', 'Has Balance1', 'CheckBox0', 'CheckBox1']
   | child_window(title="Has Balance", auto_id="HasBalanceCheckEdit", control_type="CheckBox")

Comment: Maybe `depth=2` added some confusion. Now it means immediate children only. We will change it to "immediate children + 1 more level" because `depth=1` should mean "immediate children" I think.

Comment: But this change is intended for next major release planned in summer 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you provided, next level spec `TCheckBox` is not needed. Just use this code:

```
checkbox = app.Dialog.child_window(title='Has Balance', auto_id='HasBalanceCheckEdit', control_type='CheckBox').wrapper_object()
```

Explicit `ButtonWrapper` instantiation is also not necessary because the control type is already auto detected by `.wrapper_object()`. That's why `control_type='CheckBox'` in your `child_window` can find the control.

Comment: I tried that, but getting below error:                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CCMP_Agreements.py", line 23, in <module>
    checkbox.GetCheckState()
AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'GetCheckState'

Comment: I got it. i was passing "Uia" control and was importing win32 wrapper. Issue resolved. Thanks Vasily.

Comment: Great, you can post your own answer and mark it as accepted. To show other readers it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

used `import pywinauto.controls.uia_controls` to resolve the above code.